# Joomla live_site and mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, joomla

I installed Joomla 2.5 in `/joomla/`.
It's accessible by `http://www.example.com/joomla/`.

But I want it to be accessible when I browse `http://www.example.com/` (or `example.com`, without `www`)

I thought configuration `$live_site` is because of this, but change it to `http://www.example.com/`, and it showed a blank page.

Should I edit root directory `.htaccess`? or Joomla `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: No you should only need t use $live_site if you have a strange server set up.  Your joomla .htaccess will do this,usually if your host has a .htaccess already you paste the Joomla stuff at the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

**Redirecting non-www version to www**

You can Redirect your domain from "non-WWW" to "WWW".
To redirect your domain to "WWW" you need to define a rule in your ".htaccess" file.
You can upload this file in the "root" directory of your site

For that you can set a rule as follows :

```
*******************************************
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (on)?
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?!www\.)(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteRule .? http(?%1s)://www.%2%3 [R=301,L]
********************************************
```

After defining the above rule in your ".htaccess" file When you type your domain in URL domainname.com it will get
redirected to WWW.